# Issue with MTAudioProcessingTap on device

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm trying to create an MTAudioProcessingTap based on the tutorial from this blog entry - http://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/

The issue is working with various audio formats.  I've been able to successfully create a tap with M4A's, but it is not working with MP3's.  Even stranger to me - the code works on a simulator with both formats, but not on the device (only m4a works).  I'm getting OSStatusError code 50 in my process block, and if I attempt to use the AudioBufferList data, I'll get a bad access.  The tap setup and callbacks I'm using are below.  The process block seems to be the culprit (I think) but I do not know why.

**Update** - It seems like it is very sporadically working on the first time after a bit of a break, but only the first time.  I get the feeling there is some sort of lock on my audio file.  Does anyone know what should be doing in the unprepare block for clean up?

Unprepare block -

```
void unprepare(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap)
{
NSLog(@"Unpreparing the Audio Tap Processor");
}
```

Process block (will get OSStatus error 50) -

```
void process(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, CMItemCount numberFrames,
         MTAudioProcessingTapFlags flags, AudioBufferList *bufferListInOut,
         CMItemCount *numberFramesOut, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags *flagsOut)
{
OSStatus err = MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(tap, numberFrames, bufferListInOut,
                                                  flagsOut, NULL, numberFramesOut);
if (err) NSLog(@"Error from GetSourceAudio: %ld", err);
}
```

Tap Setup -

```
NSURL *assetURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DLP" withExtension:@"mp3"];
assert(assetURL);

// Create the AVAsset
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:assetURL];
assert(asset);

// Create the AVPlayerItem
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
assert(playerItem);

assert([asset tracks]);
assert([[asset tracks] count]);

self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
assert(self.player);

// Continuing on from where we created the AVAsset...
AVAssetTrack *audioTrack = [[asset tracks] objectAtIndex:0];
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *inputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:audioTrack];

// Create a processing tap for the input parameters
MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks callbacks;
callbacks.version = kMTAudioProcessingTapCallbacksVersion_0;
callbacks.clientInfo = (__bridge void *)(self);
callbacks.init = init;
callbacks.prepare = prepare;
callbacks.process = process;
callbacks.unprepare = unprepare;
callbacks.finalize = finalize;

MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap;
// The create function makes a copy of our callbacks struct
OSStatus err = MTAudioProcessingTapCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &callbacks,
                                          kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PostEffects, &tap);
if (err || !tap) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to create the Audio Processing Tap");
    return;
}
assert(tap);

// Assign the tap to the input parameters
inputParams.audioTapProcessor = tap;
// Create a new AVAudioMix and assign it to our AVPlayerItem
AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
audioMix.inputParameters = @[inputParams];
playerItem.audioMix = audioMix;

// And then we create the AVPlayer with the playerItem, and send it the play message...
[self.player play];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was apparently a bug in 6.0 (which my device was still on).  Simulator was on 6.1

Upgraded device to 6.1.2 and errors disappeared.

Comment: I've been trying use MTAudioProcessingTap and have spent days trying to figure out how to get it deallocated when I'm done with it. Maybe you can help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19202306/506796