# How do you release an MTAudioProcessingTap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, avfoundation

The header file for MTAudioProcessingTap says that its initialization and prepare callbacks will be balanced by unprepare and finalize callbacks. However, in [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AudioTapProcessor/Introduction/Intro.html), these callbacks never get called (I added logging to them to so I could check). The header file says they will be called when the object is deallocated.

In Apple's example, the Tap is passed into a retain parameter in audioMixInputParameters, which are passed into the audio mix, where it is no longer publicly accessible:

```
MTAudioProcessingTapRef audioProcessingTap;
if (noErr == MTAudioProcessingTapCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &callbacks, kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PreEffects, &audioProcessingTap))
{
    audioMixInputParameters.audioTapProcessor = audioProcessingTap;

    CFRelease(audioProcessingTap);

    audioMix.inputParameters = @[audioMixInputParameters];

    _audioMix = audioMix;
}
```

I would expect AudioMix therefore to be responsible for releasing it in its own dealloc method, and for AudioMix to be released when the associated PlayerItem is released.

Apple's example uses an AVPlayer that only ever plays one item, so maybe it has no need to deallocate anything directly. But in my case, I'm using an AVQueuePlayer so I keep passing it new AVPlayerItems. I think it's leaking the Taps that I'm creating for each player item (along with associated audio units), even though the player items get deallocated.

What's the proper way to deallocate the MTAudioProcessingTap and get its unprepare and finalize callbacks to fire when I'm done with its associated player item?

**Update**: I found that it actually is still accessible through the audio mix, but releasing it like this doesn't trigger the unprepare and finalize callbacks:

```
((AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *)audioMix.inputParameters[0]).audioTapProcessor = nil;
```

Neither does this:

```
MTAudioProcessingTapRef audioProcessingTap = ((AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *)audioMix.inputParameters[0]).audioTapProcessor;
CFRelease(audioProcessingTap);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. To make it work, I had to reset the player item's `audioMix`, the tap processor (`MYAudioTapProcessor` in Apple's sample project) and manually release the `MTAudioProcessingTapRef`:

```
MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap = ((AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *)_audioTapProcessor.audioMix.inputParameters[0]).audioTapProcessor;
_player.currentItem.audioMix = nil;
_audioTapProcessor = nil;
CFRelease(tap);
```

This causes the `finalize` callback to be invoked.

**Edit:** Seems like the `CFRelease` is *not* required, see comments.

Comment: Thank you! I'll add that this also causes the unprepare callback to be called (before finalize). Also, my playerItem was getting deallocated too early sometimes (before the finalize callback), so I added a strong reference to the playerItem in the MYAudioTapProcessor, and use that reference instead. So I replaced `_player.currentItem.audioMix = nil;` with `_audioTapProcessor.playerItem.audioMix = nil;`.

Comment: I'll also add that you should not call CFRelease on the tap if you are going to continue using the AVPlayer, as the tap is then over-released. When you continue playing audio with a new tap, the old one's unprepare and finalize callbacks will fire.

Comment: CFRelease(tap) should be called (probably after assigning it to the mix parameters). MTAudioProcessingTapCreate, as its name implies, returns an object you have to release (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html)

Comment: For the swift version I had to replace `CFRelease(tap);` with `tap.release()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @glm4 In Swift you cant release MTProcessingTap object. .release() method is available in something like Unmanaged<MTProcessingTap> but how are you doing it from the answer above ?