# How to get unprepare and finalize callbacks to fire for multiple MTAudioProcessingTaps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

After reading this post: [How do you release an MTAudioProcessingTap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202306/how-do-you-release-an-mtaudioprocessingtap), following chris's suggestion for one tap seems to work and the unprepare and finalize callbacks are called.

However, I have more than one audio track and one tap for each.  Unlike Apple's WWDC example, my `MYAudioTapProcessor` no longer generates the audio mix, as there are multiple tracks, and hence multiple `AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters` given to the `audioMix`'s `inputParameters`.

When using multiple taps, I store an NSMutableArray of `MYAudioTapProcessor`s in `_audioProcessors`,  strong reference to the player `playerItem` and the `audioMix` in the view controller containing the `AVPlayer`.  When tearing down the player, I follow this pattern:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _audioMix.inputParameters.count; i++) {
    MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap = ((AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *)_audioMix.inputParameters[i]).audioTapProcessor;
                CFRelease(tap);
}
_audioMix = nil;
_playerItem = nil;
_player = nil;
_audioProcessors = nil;
```

Yet almost every time, one of the taps' unprepare and finalize callbacks never get called and the MTAudioProcessingTap hangs around in memory.  What's the proper way to store and deallocate multiple taps to make sure each tap's callbacks fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the referenced post is the proper way.

In my case, it was an unrelated issue with tearing down the player.  It turns out that having strong references to `periodicTimeObservers` and `boundaryTimeObservers` still on the `AVPlayer` caused the player to hang around for longer than expected.

When leaving the view controller (the time at which I want to destroy the `AVPlayer`) I removed any `AVPlayerLayer`s created from the `AVPlayer` from their superview and nil-ed them, then took the same steps as stated above, except I did not release the individual taps with `CFRelease`.  This was taken care of by nil-ing `_audioMix` and `_playerItem`.

Comment: Yes, I think the root of the difficulty in getting a tap to release is all the strong references that keep the audio mix and player alive. There seems to be a strong reference loop that can only be broken by manually nilling some of these classes' references to each other before dropping your own references to them. In my case it was `audioMix.audioTapProcessor` and `MYAudioTapProcessor.audioMix`. And I agree you should not call `CFRelease` on the tap CF object, because that breaks the contract (it's not balanced by a `CFRetain` in your own code) and will cause crashes.

Comment: CFRelease(tap) should be called (probably after assigning it to the mix parameters). MTAudioProcessingTapCreate, as its name implies, returns an object you have to release (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html)