# How to correctly stop and remove an audioTapProcessor in iOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I'm using an audioTapProcessor similar to the [audioTap example from apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AudioTapProcessor/Introduction/Intro.html).

Basically, the audioTapProcessor is created and added to the audioMix:

```
MTAudioProcessingTapRef audioProcessingTap;
if (noErr == MTAudioProcessingTapCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &callbacks,     kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PreEffects, &audioProcessingTap))
{
    audioMixInputParameters.audioTapProcessor = audioProcessingTap;

    CFRelease(audioProcessingTap);

    audioMix.inputParameters = @[audioMixInputParameters];

    _audioMix = audioMix;
}
```

When the audioMix is created, it is added to the currentItem of the avPlayer:

```
self.avPlayer.currentItem.audioMix = audioMix;
```

When i'm done with the audioTapProcessor, I clean out references to the audioTapProcessor and the audioMix:

```
if (self.avPlayer.currentItem.audioMix){

    for (AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *inputParameter in player.currentItem.audioMix.inputParameters) {
        inputParameter.audioTapProcessor = nil;

    }

    player.currentItem.audioMix = nil;
}
```

This triggers the *tap_UnprepareCallback* and the *tap_FinalizeCallback* functions, and the audioTapProcessor objects get's deallocated.

This worked without any issues until iOS11 came out a couple of days ago.

On iOS11 devices, I sometimes receive an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the ClientProcessingTapManager Thread. The error occurs in one of the classes of AVFoundation, so I can't debug. The error occurs somewhere in ClientProcessingTap::PerformTap.

I have added logging to the audioTap callbacks, and it looks like only the tap_ProcessCallBack is executed on the ClientProcessingTapManager thread.

I think that sometimes the tap_ProcessCallback method of an audioTapProcessor is triggered on this thread, while the actual audioTapProcessor is already deallocated on another Thread.

My question is: how can I correctly stop an audioTapProcessor and remove it from memory?

---

This is some example output logging:

```
2017-09-22 12:49:26:171 xx[1261:780894] cleaning up audioMix of AvPlayer
2017-09-22 12:49:26:213 xx[1261:781173] into tap_ProcessCallback. thread: ClientProcessingTapManager
2017-09-22 12:49:26:213 xx[1261:781173] end of tap_ProcessCallback
2017-09-22 12:49:26:217 xx[1261:781127] into tap_UnprepareCallback. 
2017-09-22 12:49:26:218 xx[1261:781127] end of tap_UnprepareCallback
2017-09-22 12:49:26:218 xx[1261:781127] into tap_FinalizeCallback. 
2017-09-22 12:49:26:218 Tunify[1261:781127] end of tap_FinalizeCallback
2017-09-22 12:49:26:218 Tunify[1261:781127] into MYAudioTapProcessor dealloc.
(lldb)
```

---

Good to know:

I'm usng a pool of avPlayers, so i'm reusing these objects. When I don't clean out the audioMix of my avPlayers I don't run into this error. Without the cleaning up of the audioMix objects, the audioTapProcessors are only deallocated when I reuse an avPlayer and assign a new audioMix to the avPlayer.

---

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202306/how-do-you-release-an-mtaudioprocessingtap), but i'm already triggering the cleanup functions. The solution there gives the same error on iOS11 devices

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in AVFoundation under iOS 11. It has been fixed in iOS 12.
A radar for the issue [rdar://34977000](http://rdar://34977000)

A possible workaround is to call prepareReleaseAudioMix: just before releasing the AVPlayer / AVPlayerItem

```
+ (void)prepareReleaseAudioMix:(AVAudioMix*)audioMix {
    if ( @available(iOS 11.0, *) ) {
        // Starting with iOS 11, it is not required to manually nil audioTapProcessor,
        // but we need to retain the audioMix for a bit to make sure the processing callback
        // will not be called after we release (this is due to a bug in iOS 11 which calls the release
        // callback but still calls the processing callback afterwards - it also releases internal data
        // on release, so simply checking for release in the processing block is not enough)
        // rdar://34977000
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self _prepareReleaseAudioMixNow:audioMix];
        });
    } else {
        // Prior to iOS 11 we need to manually nil the audioTapProcessor
        [self _prepareReleaseAudioMixNow:audioMix];
    }
}

+ (void)_prepareReleaseAudioMixNow:(AVAudioMix*)audioMix {
    for ( AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *parameters in audioMix.inputParameters ) {
        if ( ![parameters isKindOfClass:[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters class]] )
            continue;
        parameters.audioTapProcessor = nil;
    }
}
```